# Solving the functional equation $f(xy)=f(f(x)+f(y))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

> Find all functions from $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x$ and $y$  $$f (xy)=f (f (x)+f (y))$$

I've put $x$ and $y$ as $0$ and $1$. How to proceed after substituting if we don't know what the function is?

Comment: Is this problem from a book, an exercise sheet...? (This would help in determining how hard it's expected to be)

Comment: $f(x)=C$ for any $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is one class of solutions.

Comment: Its from a book on functional equations for the 9th grade.

Comment: $y=0$: $f(0)=f(f(x)+f(0))$. If you note $g(x)=f(x)+f(0)$, you see that $g \circ g$ is constant. That should shorten the list of possibilities

Comment: It's relatively easy to show that there are no linear, non constant solutions

Comment: @Alex H. it's really not enough, take $g(\mathbb Q)=1, g(\mathbb R - \mathbb Q) = 0$, $g \circ g = 1$, but there is no $f$ for it

Comment: In fact there are no polynomial solutions, use y=1, check leading coefficient left and right, see it must be 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f( 0 ) = f( f(x) + f(0) )$$
Thus in particular, $f(2f(0))=f(0)$.
Then let $y=2f(0)$ in the original equality, we get 
$$f( x \cdot 2f(0) ) = f( f(x) + f(2f(0)) ) = f( f(x) + f(0) ) = f(0)$$
If $f(0)$ is not equal to $0$, we're done.

Now assume $f(0) = 0$, and from above one obtains $f( f(x) ) = 0$.
Let $y = f(1)$, leads 
$$f( x \cdot f(1) ) = f( f(x) + f( f(1) ) ) = f( f(x) ) = 0$$
If $f(1)$ is not equal to $0$, we're done.

While if $f(1) = 0$, then let $y=1$, and $f(x)=f( f(x) ) = 0$.
Thus the only solution is constant.

Comment: Sorry, I really dont see the logic of this prove. What do you want to do with $y=2f(0)$? You seem to use a property you got from $y=0$ in the general case. How can this be possible? And I cannot follow the rest of your argument aswell. What am I missing? Can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: f(x⋅2f(0))=f(f(x)+f(2f(0)))=f(f(x)+f(0))=f(0). The first equality is gotten from the original condition by substituting y with 2f(0), then the second comes from  f(2f(0))=f(0), and f(0)=f(f(x)+f(0)) leads the final.

Comment: OK, i understand now, was confused with your different cases. Nice solution, nice way to solve such an equation. +1

Answer (score 2):

**Injective case only**:
As suggested by you and in the comments, we use $\{x,y\}=\{0,1\}$:

$y=0$:

1. $$f(0)=f\big(f(x)+f(0)\big)$$

$x=y=0$:

2. $$f(0)=f\big(2f(0)\big)$$

so we see: $(1)=(2)$ ->
$$f\big(f(x)+f(0)\big)=f\big(2f(0)\big)\\
f(x)+f(0)=2f(0)\\
f(x)=f(0)=c
$$

We test what $c$ can be: $f(xy)= c = f(2c) = c$ which is true $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$

So the only solution: $f(x)=c$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$, (and could easily be generalized to the complex domain $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, with $c \in \mathbb{C}$).

Comment: You've only shown that the only injective solution is the constant function. There remains to see what happens in the other case.

Comment: You are right, I use the inverse, which is defined for the injective case only. Thanks for pointing this out.